# Ruby on Rails - How do I not publish posts until it has been marked reviewed by an Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on my first application, similar to a Pinterest where users can make posts. Right now, all posts made are instantly posted. How do I build in an admin approval process so that posts are not published until an admin approves each post?

So I created a boolean called "pinreview" under "Pins" that is initially blank for each post made. How would I edit the controller so that the pins viewable by public in the index and show view, along with the pagination on index view, will only account for "Pins" that have been approved? If this can be done, how can I build an admin page that allows an admin to view the non-public post submissions and check off the "pinreview" checkbox?

I have attached my code below. Thanks!

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "pins", :force => true do |t|
    ...
    t.boolean  "pinreview"
end
```

**pins_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @pins = Pin.order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @pins }
  end
end

def show
  @pin = Pins.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @pin }
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render @pins %>
<%= will_paginate @pins %>
```

**_pins.html.erb**

```
<%= pin.name %>
<%= pin.description %>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to your Pin model:

```
scope :approved, where(:pinreview => false)
scope :pending,  where(:pinreview => true)
```

I'm going to suggest another scope to help clean up your controller a wee bit:

```
scope :newest, order("created_at desc")
```

Then, you can query on those scopes:

```
@pins = Pin.approved.newest.page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
```

To get unapproved Pins, just change your scope:

```
@pins = Pin.pending.newest.page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. 

But is there a way to restrict access to the "pending" posts by public? Because I can still access it manually by entering in URL (localhost:3000/pins/##).

Comment: Also, my boolean right now by default is "blank" so I tried changing schema.rb to show the following:

    t.boolean  "pinreview",      :default => false

But my new posts are not default false. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you have to do some authorization whether it can be view. or something like if user.admin?
 then display else not display end

Comment: @stephenliu Just make your `#show` action include the `approved` scope when finding a post.

Answer (score 1):

What I found also helpful was to integrate a "before_action" method in the controller if you generally don't want to display any Pins currently under review.

```
before_action :is_approved, only: :index

def is_approved
    @pins = Pin.all.where(:pinreview => false)
end
```

Hope this might help someone looking for a overall solution not displaying any content, for example on index